# Set one resource integer to another in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to set one `System:Int32` resource to another in XAML?

I would like to do something along the lines of :

```
<System:Int32 x:Key="SomeValue">9999</System:Int32>

<System:Int32 x:Key="MoreSpecificValue">
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="SomeValue"/>
</System:Int32>
```

Comment: You mean to share resource across XAML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A StaticResource must not attempt to make a forward reference to a resource that is defined lexically further within the XAML file. Attempting to do so is not supported, and even if such a reference does not fail, attempting the forward reference will incur a load time performance penalty when the internal hash tables representing a ResourceDictionary are searched. **For best results, adjust the composition of your resource dictionaries such that forward references can be avoided.** If you cannot avoid a forward reference, use DynamicResource Markup Extension instead.

For More Info : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)